# is there a secure way to store user credential in google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, security

Now I am using Auth 2.0 to generate user access token and refresh token in my rest api, in  flutter I could using secure storage class to store the auth info. But in google chrome extension, I want to call the rest api and also need to store the refresh token and access token. But I could not find a secure way to do this. Now I am store in chrome.storage.local like this:

```
chrome.storage.local.set(
 {
    accessToken: accessToken,
    refreshToken: refreshToken,
 },
 function () {
       retryTimes = retryTimes + 1;
       subChannel(e, retryTimes);
    }
 );
```

it is not secure, another google chrome app could read the value,so any secure way to do this? or what should I do to save user credential in Google Chrome or in browser using best secure way?